# deleteRowAtIndexPath does not actually delete the row

Tags: ios, uitableview

trying to delete a row from `UITableView` and everything works fine except when I am deleting the last row left `(at index 0,0)` in which case I get an error saying

```
The number of sections contained in the table view after the update 
(0) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table
view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections
inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'
```

This occurs right after it reaches

```
[tableView endUpdates];
```

which is right after the delete rows function.

Any idea why does the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` function not work? I checked the `indexPath` and it is showing 0,0 just as it should.

Thanks

Comment: I think you must make number of sections less when you are deleting last row of a particular section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you delete a row you should make sure your method:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Returns proper amount of sections - in your case if you delete a row, sections should remain the same - and according to error you are decreasing the value returned by that function.

Also this method

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Must return proper values (which is row - 1) after deleting one row.

Paste more code so we can identify where the problem is exactly.

Comment: Oh no, thanks a lot, I just now realised that sections are the problem, no idea why did I read that error as a problem with rows. Thanks a lot